# Class inheritance and __new___

Tags: python

I'm having a load of confusion between the `__metaclass__` property of a class and actual inheritance, and how `__new__` is called in either of these scenarios.  My issue comes from digging through some model code in the django framework.

Let's say I wanted to append an attribute to a class as it's defined in the child's `Meta` subclass:

```
class Parent(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, base, attrs):
        meta = attrs.pop('Meta', None)
        new_class = super(Parent, cls).__new__(cls, name, base, attrs)
        new_class.fun = getattr(meta, 'funtime', None)
        return new_class
```

I don't understand why the actual `__new__` method is called in django's code, but when I try to code something like that it doesn't work.

From what I've experienced, the following does not actually call the `__new__` method of the parent:

```
class Child(Parent):
    class Meta:
       funtime = 'yaaay'

C = Child()
```

When I try to do this it complains with the TypeError:

`TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`

However the source code I have been looking at appears to work in that way.

I understand that it could be done with a metaclass:

```
class Child(object):
    __metaclass__ = Parent
```

But I don't understand why their way works for them and not for me, since the non `__metaclass___` would be cleaner for making a distributable module.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django, `Model` is not a metaclass. Actually the metaclass is `ModelBase`. That's why their way works and your way doesn't work. 
Moreover, the latest django used a helper function, [`six.with_metaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/utils/six.py#L364), to wrap 'ModelBase'.

If we want to follow django's style, `Parent` and `Child` class will look like

```
def with_metaclass(meta, base=object):
    """Create a base class with a metaclass."""
    return meta("NewBase", (base,), {})

class ParentBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, attrs):
        meta = attrs.pop('Meta', None)
        new_class = super(ParentBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, base, attrs)
        new_class.fun = getattr(meta, 'funtime', None)
        return new_class

class Parent(with_metaclass(ParentBase)):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    class Meta:
       funtime = 'yaaay'

c = Child()

>>> c.fun
'yaaay'
```

Let us focus on `Parent`. It is almost equivalent to

```
NewBase = ParentBase("NewBase", (object,), {})
class Parent(NewBase):
    pass
```

The key is how to understand `ParentBase("NewBase", (object,), {})`.
Let us recall [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

> type(name, bases, dict)
>
> > With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement. The name string is the class name and becomes the **name** attribute; the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the **bases** attribute; and the dict dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the **dict** attribute. For example, the following two statements create identical type objects:

Since `ParentBase` is a metaclass, a subclass of `type`. Therefore, `ParentBase("NewBase", (object,), {})` is very similar to `type("NewBase", (object,), {})`. In this case, the only difference is the class created dynamically is not an instance of `type`, but `ParentBase`.
In other word, the metaclass of `NewBase` is `ParentBase`. `Parent` is equivalent to

```
class NewBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = ParentBase

class Parent(NewBase):
    pass
```

Finally, we got a `__metaclass__`.

Comment: That totally makes sense, but their source-code contains no lines ever stating a __metaclass__.  I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Look at their ModelBase code for example: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py

Comment: Took a third look at they use six.with_metaclass(BaseClass) to handle this ... interesting.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DevinS, I updated my post and explained the use of `with_metaclass`.

Answer (score 1):

in a metaclass that extends `type`, `__new__` is used to create a class.

in a class, `__new__` is used to create an instance.

metaclass is a class that creates a class. you're confused of class inheritance and metaclass.

your `Child` class inherits `Parent` and you want to create an instance of `Child`. however, `Parent` being a metaclass means `Parent.__new__` shouldn't be used to create an instance of a class.

Comment: I'm confused by your last statement.  Since Parent top class is 'type', doesn't the MRO bring it back to `type.__new__(...)` to create the class?